# Autoencoder con imágenes RGB

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de realizar un autoencoder para poder aplicar luego un algoritmo de clustering para clasificación de imágenes.

Me estoy basando en un ejemplo de clustering de imágenes con autoencoders mediante un ejemplo con la base de datos de MNIST (Dígitos escritos a mano).

El problema, es que mis imágenes tienen los 3 canales de color RGB, y me resulta muy complicado poder adaptarlo a mi lote de imágenes.

He intentado con una red convolucional, pero no termina de reconstruirme bien la imagen.
Si tenéis algún consejo, o ayuda, se agradecería.

Dejo el código del autoencoder en el cual me estoy basando, mis imágenes son de 200x200 pixeles con RGB, es decir (200, 200, 3) cuando las MNIST son (28, 28, 1):

```
def autoencoder(dims, act='relu', init='glorot_uniform'):
    """
    Fully connected auto-encoder model, symmetric.
    Arguments:
        dims: list of number of units in each layer of encoder. dims[0] is input dim, dims[-1] is units in hidden layer.
            The decoder is symmetric with encoder. So number of layers of the auto-encoder is 2*len(dims)-1
        act: activation, not applied to Input, Hidden and Output layers
    return:
        (ae_model, encoder_model), Model of autoencoder and model of encoder
    """
    n_stacks = len(dims) - 1
    # input
    input_img = Input(shape=(dims[0],), name='input')
    x = input_img
    # internal layers in encoder
    for i in range(n_stacks-1):
        x = Dense(dims[i + 1], activation=act, kernel_initializer=init, name='encoder_%d' % i)(x)

    # hidden layer
    encoded = Dense(dims[-1], kernel_initializer=init, name='encoder_%d' % (n_stacks - 1))(x)  # hidden layer, features are extracted from here

    x = encoded
    # internal layers in decoder
    for i in range(n_stacks-1, 0, -1):
        x = Dense(dims[i], activation=act, kernel_initializer=init, name='decoder_%d' % i)(x)

    # output
    x = Dense(dims[0], kernel_initializer=init, name='decoder_0')(x)
    decoded = x
    return Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=decoded, name='AE'), Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=encoded, name='encoder')
```

Dejo también el enlace al GitHub del código que estoy usando de ejemplo:

https://github.com/Tony607/Keras_Deep_Clustering/blob/master/Keras-DEC.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

Para imitar el ejemplo de Mnist, necesitas tranformar tus imágenes a blanco y negro, para poder tener un solo canal de color. Puedes usar la biblioteca `OpenCV` que es de las más usadas en tratamiento de imagenes.

Para instalarla usa: `pip install opencv-python`

Una vez instalada puedes realizar el siguiente código para transformar las imagenes a escala de grises, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

## 1. Leyendo las imágenes

Leer las imágenes directamente en escala de grises, usando la función `imread()` y **poniendo el cero como parámetro**

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg', 0)
```

## 2. Transformar imágenes de color a escala de grises

Si por lo que sea, quieres tener previamente las imágenes a color, utiliza la función `cvtColor()` indicándole que lo vas a **pasar de RGB a gris**

```
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Esto hará que tus imagenes pasen de (200, 200, 3) a (200, 200, 1), que es lo que necesitas. Has quitado los tres canales de color **RGB** y te has quedado con un canal **escala de grises**